# Ignite Yarn and Hortonworks

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, ignite

I'm trying to deploy ignite so that I can use the shared RDD/Dataframe cache for my spark cluster. I've followed the spark install instructions and choose to deploy into my existing yarn cluster running spark. I'm using HDP to deploy spark.

I've already verified that Resource Manager and History server are listening on the ports below and I can telnet to each port. What am I doing wrong? Am I not deploying this the way it is intended?

I'm running:

```
yarn jar ignite-yarn-2.6.0.jar ./ignite-yarn-2.6.0.jar ../../../cluster.properties
```

Error below:

```
18/09/24 22:13:38 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at dev01clus02.dna.local/172.31.31.5:8050
18/09/24 22:13:38 INFO client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at dev01clus02.dna.local/172.31.31.5:10200
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed update ignite.
        at org.apache.ignite.yarn.IgniteProvider.updateIgnite(IgniteProvider.java:243)
        at org.apache.ignite.yarn.IgniteProvider.getIgnite(IgniteProvider.java:93)
        at org.apache.ignite.yarn.IgniteYarnClient.getIgnite(IgniteYarnClient.java:194)
        at org.apache.ignite.yarn.IgniteYarnClient.main(IgniteYarnClient.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:704)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:675)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at org.apache.ignite.yarn.IgniteProvider.updateIgnite(IgniteProvider.java:220)
        ... 9 more
```

Comment: For understanding root of the issue needed your cluster.properties file. Could you share it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a piece of insfrastructure, provided by GridGain for Apache Ignite project, does not work currently. I'll raise the issue.

In the meantime, you can provide `IGNITE_PATH` property (in config, system properties or env) pointed to unzipped Apache Ignite 2.6 distribution directory to avoid downloading attempts altogether.